# How to choose to use GPU with tf.device() in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I run tensorflow example from models/cifar10/cifar10_train.py, in the example script, they said it will use one GPU, but I did find they define to use GPU like with tf.device('/gpu:0'): 
and they define store some intermediate variable with CPU, so I wander how does tensorflow handle the GPU and CPU? To use GPU is the default choice???
Here is the link for the example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html
Any advice will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance
Good day

Comment: GPU is default choice

Comment: Thanks, the example script run the cifar-10 dataset uses 4-5 hours with one GPU Tesla K40.

Comment: In my case, I use Quadro K4000, it seems that it will take 60 hours, I did not check out the comparision for the two GPU, but mine is quite slow...

Comment: Ah, in that case it may be running on CPU, by default it only uses GPUs that have more than 8 streaming multiprocessors

Comment: I checkout my GPU usage with nvidia-smi, here is the result and the process of the example code outputs, I think the example code does use GPU to run the script, but it is incredible slow, I compared the example/sec, it is less than the tensorflow website, but not so much, in the example script, they just use CPU to store some checkout point and summary files, So I am a little confused, I also attached the cuda-devicequery.

Comment: I cant upload images....but, in the command nvdia-smi, I do have process on GPU for tensorflow

Comment: but if the example script cost me 80 hours to run, I am not so convinced that we use the GPU, because it is quite slow....